# How to get object attribute with weird name

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a situation where the name of an attribute is xml namespace::element (e.g. `http://giggle.com/some/Path::Element`). It is weird situation because I can read it, but I can't access it.
Here is an example:

```
var name: String = "http://giggle.com/some/Path::Element";
var obj: Object = createAttributes(name);

// Now we have obj:{ "http://giggle.com/some/Path::Element" : [an array] }

for (var attr : Object in obj[name]){
    // do something
}
```

This is just a simplification of the real thing. It seems like I can't read it neither with `obj.name`, nor `obj[name]`, nor `obj['"' + name + '"']`.

I have even tried something like this (with different types for elem):

```
for (var elem: Object in obj) { // I tried Object, Array and * here
    for (var c: Object in elem)
    {
        // do something with c
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how to overcome this issue? Since it is interesting problem, please don't consider changing the way I create obj. AS3 allows creation of such attribute and I am wandering how we are suppose to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess Object's **key** is what that you named "weird name".

key could be name or index id (numbers in string format "1", "2",..)

```
for (var key:String in obj) {
    var value:* = obj[key];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, It does work. Sorry, I am new to AS3 and I have expected to get real objects from for each, but I got just a string instead.